# Has the google oauth API response changed for email scope? The type of email has changed from 'account' to 'ACCOUNT'

Tags: google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

We are using google login in our website and spring social library to implement oAuth 2. After getting accessToken , with scope as userInfo.email, we are trying to retrieve accountEmail. spring-social-google(version 1.0.0) is looking for key "account" in the emails property of the reponse. Below is code block from spring-social-sources  org.springframework.social.google.api.plus.Person.class

```
public String getAccountEmail() {
    if (emails != null) {
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : emails.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals("account")) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

From Oct 27, google is responding with email map as "ACCOUNT" instead of "account"

```
Expert from logs before 27th - getEmails :: {xxxxxxx@gmail.com=account} 
Expert from logs after 27th - getEmails :: {xxxxxxx@gmail.com=ACCOUNT}
```

I could not find any documentmentation from google regarding the change or reponse format. When i use API playground, i can see the type is coming as 'ACCOUNT'.

```
   "image": {
"url": "....photo.jpg", 
"isDefault": true }, 
"etag": "xxx", 
"id": "xxx", 
"kind": "plus#person", 
"emails": [
  {
  "type": "ACCOUNT", 
  "value": "xxxx@gmail.com"
  }
]
}
```

I just wanted to check if any one else faced the issue or if anyone has a documentation from google, which explains why the change happened.

Comment: Yes, hit this exact issue and had to figure it out today.

Comment: Wow, you saved me a ton of time with that question. Thank you. It would be wonderful if you could also share your solution